# JQuery validator not validating form

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

**Note**: the `regex` stuff is experimental, I've tried it without and still doesn't work, if possible though can someone tell me if anything's wrong with it?

I can't see what I'm doing wrong here. There are also other functions that are exectued correctly in the `document.ready`, so I don't think it's that either.

My code:

```
function checkForm() {
$.validator.addMethod("regex", function(value, element, regexpr) {          
    return regexpr.test(value);
} );
$('#contactform').validate( { 
    rules: { 
        first: {
            required: true,
            minLength: true,
            regex: /^[A-z]{2,}$/
        },
        last: {
            required: true,
            minLength: true,
            regex: /^[A-z]{2,}(-[A-z]{2,})?$/
        },
        titledd: 'required',
        zhanum: {
            required: true,
            regex: /^(ZHA|zha)([0-9]{6})$/
        },
        emailadd: { 
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        telephone: {
            regex: /^[0-9]{5,16}$/
        }
    },
    messages: {
        first: {
            required: "You must enter a first name",
            minLength: "Your first name must have more than 2 characters",
            regex: "Please enter a first name with more than two characters, where only letters are allowed"
        },
        last: {
            required: "You must enter a last name",
            minLength: "Your last name must have more than 2 characters",
            regex: "Please enter a last name with more than two characters, where only letters and optionally one hyphen are allowed"
        },
        titledd: {
            required: "Please select your title"
        },
        zhanum: {
            required: "You must enter your ZHA number",
            regex: "Your ZHA number should be ZHA followed by six numbers only"
        },
        emailadd: { 
            required: "You must enter an email address",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"
        },
        telephone: {
            regex: "Please enter a telephone number with more than five characters and less than 16 characters, where only numbers are allowed"
        }
    }
} );
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    checkForm();
} );
```

Comment: Whats the error also try changing the function name from `regex` to `rehex1`

Comment: It's not coming up with an error, it's just not stopping it from submitting if nothing is entered in the fields

Comment: You mean if user has not entered anything then it show no error.. Can u show some more part of ur code ?

Comment: Yes, and regardless of what is entered it doesn't see any errors from it. The rest of the code is minor things, like a default text in one of the fields and a tool tip, which load fine.

Comment: Try removing function and document.ready .. Paste the selector part just after the form without keeping it inside a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was in my HTML I had `id` attributes instead of `name` attributes, I didn't realise this was an issue.

Comment: You did not show the HTML in the question, so there was no way for anyone else to correctly answer this.  Since this issue has been addressed many times before, please consider deleting your question.  Thanks.

Comment: I know, I can't delete it since it has answers though, I will flag it

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
$.validator.addMethod("regex", function(value, element, regexpr) {          
    return regexpr.test(value);
} );
$('#contactform').validate( { 
    rules: { 
        first: {
            required: true,
            minLength: true,
            regex: /^[A-z]{2,}$/
        },
        last: {
            required: true,
            minLength: true,
            regex: /^[A-z]{2,}(-[A-z]{2,})?$/
        },
        titledd: 'required',
        zhanum: {
            required: true,
            regex: /^(ZHA|zha)([0-9]{6})$/
        },
        emailadd: { 
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        telephone: {
            regex: /^[0-9]{5,16}$/
        }
    },
    messages: {
        first: {
            required: "You must enter a first name",
            minLength: "Your first name must have more than 2 characters",
            regex: "Please enter a first name with more than two characters, where only letters are allowed"
        },
        last: {
            required: "You must enter a last name",
            minLength: "Your last name must have more than 2 characters",
            regex: "Please enter a last name with more than two characters, where only letters and optionally one hyphen are allowed"
        },
        titledd: {
            required: "Please select your title"
        },
        zhanum: {
            required: "You must enter your ZHA number",
            regex: "Your ZHA number should be ZHA followed by six numbers only"
        },
        emailadd: { 
            required: "You must enter an email address",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"
        },
        telephone: {
            regex: "Please enter a telephone number with more than five characters and less than 16 characters, where only numbers are allowed"
        }
    }
} );
```

And make sure to keep it after `<form>` tag

Comment: What changed, is it just out of the function?

Comment: Yes it is so.. i guess because in validaot plugin i could not find a good functin example. Did it work ?